# Angular 4 Only Add New Elements To View Without Rerendering Old Items Again

Tags: angular

**Angular 4:**

I'm doing an api call by using an angular `service`. The result of a request is a list with entries. Here is the code for the template - (`pis`) is an iterable array provided by the `http-request`:

```
<tr *ngFor="let pi of pis;">
    <td>{{pi.mac}}</td>
    <td>{{pi.uptime | secondsReadable}}</td>
</tr>
```

The api call is not only executed once. So when doing a Second Api Call all Elements are getting `rerendered`.

So I thought the `tablerow` can be identified by using the mac because it is unique and only entries with new `mac-adresses` need to be added.

After some googling I think `track by` is the feature I need to implement. But I don't know how I can implement it. I'm new to `angular` and so I'm a little bit confused by the different implementations of `track by` in older angular versions and can't find a suitable example for `Angular 4.0`.

Method in components which is handling the api call:

```
getPis() {
  this.pisService.getPis()
      .subscribe(
      pis => { this.pis = pis;},
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);}
```

Comment: I dont quite understood the situation - the api call that executed more than once is the api call which brings the repeater data? actually there is ngForTrackBy option https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: @happyZZR1400 yes, the result of the api request is a list of pi entries. I updated the question

Comment: i'm afraid im still missing something here - if your second api call brings the whole list - why it is looks wrong to you all the list twill render again? usually the trackby used for prevent rerendering of the list in case when only one item has changed (new item added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to get it working.

the `*ngFor` is now looking like this: `*ngFor="let pi of pis; trackBy: trackByMac;"`.

And the `trackByMac` is a simple function in the `component class` which reads like this:

```
trackByMac(index, item){
return item.mac;}
```